# How to add specific time to existing date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a specific date and time value from date and time picker. I need to schedule a event on the specific date and time. How to append the time to the date like,

```
var date = "1/19/2017"
// and
var time = "10:04 pm"
```

How to add this specific time to the date so that event triggers only on the scheduled date and time?

Comment: what exactly you want here ?

Comment: you can `setHours` `setMinutes` `setSeconds` - it's all pretty well [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: or if you are using the strings you could just do `var date_time = date +" "+time;`

Comment: Your event scheduler might want date-time in a particular format. What is the format ? If you want only string format just concat date and time variable

Comment: event scheduler accepts the date in milliseconds .I could implement it for the current time for the specific date using gettime() method but I could n't do it for specific time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is what you want. This converts specific time to ms

```
var dateStr = "1/19/2017";
var timeStr = "10:04 pm";

var createDate = new Date(dateStr +" "+timeStr).getTime();
alert(createDate);
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/8vfnahpn/